# Counting name occurence in textfile, being sensitive to duplicates

Tags: python, regex, text, nlp, text-mining

I have a list of names and want to count the occurrences throughout a corpus of text files.

I am using a simple regex search with a dictionary to do this:

```
    for k,v in eng_names_dict.items():
        for i in v:
            pattern = re.compile(str(i).strip(' '))
            matches = re.search(pattern, text)
            if matches:
                namesDict[k] += 1
                break
    return
```

**The catch:**

I have a mix of titles and names (with different name formats as seen in the example below), with some duplicates between them.

For example: 
My list includes two different people - "Dr. Mark" (title + surname) and "Mark Smith" (first name + surname).

If a text file includes the string "Dr. Mark Smith said that..." my function marks a count for both people (instead of only for "Mark Smith").

Is there any way to ensure only one count per substring?

Comment: Yep there is, but could you post what eng_names_dict looks like so I can be sure? I don't understand why you're looping over each value so I can't be certain of my answer.

Comment: eng_names_dict looks like (sample):
{'John Smith': ['Dr. John Smith','Dr. Smith'],'Amanda Smith':['Amanda Smith','Mandy Smith','Ms. Amanda Smith'],'Jennifer Turner':['Jennifer Turner','Jenny Turner','Prof. Turner']....}

The point being a structure to aggregate different forms of the name per each person (including nicknames)

Comment: @Alan This was great (the second solution perfect) - one quick question, some of my names are not in English (Hebrew encoding) and I see that "re.findall(regex,text)" comes up empty - is there any way to take care of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah thanks for including the data structure. I think what you need is "or" functionality in regex. Consider this example

```
regex = r'Mr\. John Smith|John Smith'
re.findall(regex, "I hate Mr. John Smith)

# -> ['Mr. John Smith']
```

So to explain, the pipe in the regex acts as an "or", i.e. match either this or that but not both, and regex being greedy will match the longest of the patterns if there is nesting between them.

In the example I gave, both "Mr. John Smith" and "John Smith" were a match, but regex chose to match to the longer one. Note as well that findall() returns a list of all matches. So, applying this to your case:

```
for k,v in eng_names_dict.items():

    # Convert list of matches into one regex string
    regex = r'|'.join(v)
    matches = re.findall(regex, text)
    namesDict[k] += len(matches)
```

## EDIT

---

Okay so from your comment it seems there could be ambiguity across the values of different keys of eng_names_dict, whereas so far my answer only deals with ambiguity between values within one key.

Here are two ways to deal with the situation, and the limitations of each. With regex, sometimes there's ambiguity that has to be settled with hard coded rules.

### Scenario 1: a small number of such ambiguous cases.

If the amount of overlap between values is small and manageable, you could order your regex statements according to preference and remove the matching phrase in the text bit by bit.

So for example if we have:

```
{'Mark Smith': ['Dr. Mark Smith', 'Mark Smith'],
 'Andrew Mark': ['Dr. Mark', 'Andrew Mark']
```

*Note I am assuming that Mark Smith has a value "Dr. Mark Smith" somewhere, even though you don't say this is necessarily the case. Because if this is not true, then the problem is something totally different (in that case it would be how to match 'Mark Smith' and NOT match 'Dr. Mark Smith'.*

We can clearly see that one of Andrew's values is nested in one of Mark's. So we can choose to do Mark first (according to some rule) and then remove the phrase from the text.

```
from collections import OrderedDict 

od = OrderedDict()
od['Mark Smith'] = eng_names_dict['Mark_Smith']
od['Andrew Mark'] = eng_names_dict['Andrew Mark']

for k,v in eng_names_dict.items():

    # Convert list of matches into one regex string
    regex = r'|'.join(v)
    matches = re.findall(regex, text)
    for match in set(matches):
        text=re.sub(r'{}'.format(match, '', text)
    namesDict[k] += len(matches)
```

The disadvantage here is the manual requirement to determine the order of operations for consuming the eng_name_dicts entries.

### Scenario 2: the amount of cases is just too large

---

In this case we can just continue to use the natural behaviour of regex to choose the longest string in matches with "or". Rework the original solution a little bit. Instead of creating a small regex for each eng_names_dict key, let's create one really big one for every possible value. Regex will decide for us what the proper order is.

```
# Create one list containing all values from dict
match_vals = []
for dict_val in list(eng_names_dict.values()):
    for match_val in dict_val:
        match_vals.extend(match_val)

# Do a match on this full regex
regex = r'|'.join(match_vals)
matches = re.findall(regex, text)

# Loop through every match, and count it if it's in the vals of an entry's key
for match in matches:
    for k, v in eng_names_dict.items():
        # Nested loops will be slow; open to suggestions to improve
        if match in v:
            namesDict[k] + 1
            # Any match is unique to one person; break loop after match found
            break
```

The advantage is that regex will naturally determine the most accurate order, so you don't need to figure that out manually. The disadvantage here is that it is heavy handed, hard to debug and might impact relationships between name values that you aren't aware of yourself.

Comment: Ok, i apologize, I guess I wasn't clear in my explanation . I have two entities in "eng_names_dict" - "Mark Smith" and "Andrew Mark". "Andrew Mark"'s key also includes the value of "Dr. Mark" (another name entity under the overall entity of "Andrew Mark". If, in  my text, there is a substring "Dr. Mark Smith", I want only "Mark Smith" to be counted, and not "Andrew Mark" (due to "Dr. Mark" being found)... hope I made it more clear